# Can the United Nations Terminology Database (UNTERM) be downloaded?

Tags: data-request, un

Currently the United Nations hosts the United Nations Terminology Database at

- https://unterm.un.org/UNTERM/portal/welcome

Do they provide a data dump of this anywhere?